# How to exclude (ignore) specific tags in filters (for subscription)?

Tags: feature-request, tags, filtering, subscription

This is not about ignoring tags in the search but in the individual filters one can subscribe to via email. (Link: [Form to create such a filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/new))

To include only questions with a certain tag in the filter is pretty straight forward. Just add them with "*Just questions tagged with the*".
When several tags are in the list, they are connected with `OR`.

But is there a way to exclude questions, which do have one (or more) of the tags listed but also another one I want to ignore?
Similar to the search `[ruby] [testing] -[ruby-on-rails*]`, which selects all questions tagged with `[ruby]` and `[testing]` excluding those questions which are as well tagged with one of the `[ruby-on-rails]` tags (including `[ruby-on-rails-3]`).

If there is such a functionality not yet implemented, it would be very nice having one.