# Can a chat bot feed be made for questions tagged with [anime] tag but not if they're also tagged [identification]?

Tags: support, tags, chat, feed

Stuff has happened, and anime identification requests have flooded the Anime, Movies and SciFi. Anime banned all anime IDs completely, but SciFi and Movies still accept them. Sometimes they get interesting non-identification request questions, but a lot of the time they're IDs and posting them in our chat feed is of no use to anyone.

Is there a way to create an RSS feed with all [anime] questions from Movies, Scifi and Japanese, but filter out the questions which also have any of the [identification] tags?

Comment: I'm afraid not, as long as [this feature request to exclude tags on "Filtered Questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120014/241919) has not been implemented yet...